# CSS Propertie change OnClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple absolute positioning of 's via CSS including z-index
HTML:

```
<div id="one"> test </div>
<div id="two"> test </div>
<div id="three"> test </div>
```

CSS:

```
#one{
height: 200px;
width: 150px;
background: #a8d14f;
position: absolute;
left: 10px;
top: 30px;
z-index: 10;
}
#two{
height: 200px;
width: 150px;
background: #f97273;
position: absolute;
left: 150px;
top: 30px;
z-index: 15;
}
#three{
height: 200px;
width: 150px;
background: #43b8b0;
position: absolute;
left: 300px;
top: 30px;
z-index: 12;
}
```

Needed:
OnClick change some of CSS properties for selected  like position, z-index, background

Comment: Have you even looked at http://api.jquery.com/css/ yet?

Comment: [what have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I'm TOTAL numb in Javascript or jQuery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example of an onclick event for the `one` element, which will change its `z-index`.

```
$(function(){
  $("#one").click(function(){
     $(this).css("z-index", 2);
  });
});
```

From this you should be able to work out how to do the rest. If not, then look into the use of jQuery more. We're not here to do the work for you.

Comment: That uses jQuery.  Could just use simple JavaScript  document.getElementById('one').style.zIndex = '2';

Comment: @GlennG This is try, but considering OP wants to change quite a few styles, this seems the best method. Plus, what are you suggesting in terms of the click event listener then? Would you still use the jQuery click event? Makes sense to use `$(this)` if so.

Answer (score 2):

Or without jQuery:

```
document.getElementById("one").onclick = function() {
    with (this.style) {
        color = "red";
        position = "relative";
        zIndex = "10";
    }
};​
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. [Here's more details on how to change css properties with jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
$("#one").click(function(){
    $(this).css("position", "absolute");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Or without using jQuery

```
var one = document.getElementById("one");
one.addEventListener("click", function() {
    one.style.zIndex = 5;
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qJURY/
and this is the code used :

```
$("div").click(function(){
    var z = parseInt($(this).css("z-index"));
    z += 10;
    $(this).css("z-index", z);
})
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#one').click(function(){
   $(this).css("background-color","yellow");
   $(this).css("z-index", 1);

});
```

alternate you could use plain javascript:

```
document.getElementById('one').style.zIndex = '1'
```